# ASP.NET application can not start on Win 10 and IIS 10 - HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a ASP.NET MVC application which was running on Win 8.1 and IIS Express 7
but Microsoft changed this by force with updates and now I have Windows 10 and IIS 10.

Application stopped working today (day 1 month 4 2017).

**I end up with**

> Service Unavailable
>
> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

or

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
> The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

**Privileges**

Application pool for this app is under different account. The user has privileges to different folders. Logs are enabled.

**Problem 1**

I see nothing (significant) in any logs. It seems logs are not working. I am not sure, or I just can not see them.

**Problem 2**

After I starts application pool it stops in a few seconds.

In Event log I have only this:

**Event log**

> 1. **Error:** *Application pool 'MyApp' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.* -
> 2. **Warning:** *A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '8924' serving application pool 'MyApp' reported a listener channel failure.  The data field contains the error number.* 5139 -

**Note**

When I run this app on different computer from Visual Studio it is working.

**Question**

1. Why I don't see any error in logs? Or where to look?
2. Where to start looking for the problem?

Comment: Does it happen to yours specific app only? Have you tried a simplest MVC Hello World?

Comment: Maybe the software change could have uninstalled components that are required for running?

Comment: I have tried Hello Word on that computer from Visual Studio and it is working. I will try without VS.

Comment: @Grappachu Maybe yes but I don't think so. I am using nothing special. But if this is that case I see nothing in logs.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I just have tried new Hello World app and it is working in new Application Pool. So it is something with my old app or application pool but I don't know how to find out because I can see nothing in logs.

Comment: Are you catching errors at the app level (Application_Error) and logging everything? Most probably it is a permission issue which just causes multiple errors and IIS shuts down the pool.

Comment: @WiktorZychla  I wish is that case but is not. I am almost sure it is something with privileges or missing file but still don't know what and logs shows nothing reasonable. But I am not using custom logging for sure.
Now it seems that application can see static files but don't see default page of application ... I am trying localhost:1234 but is not working. When I use localhost:1234/something/img.jpg it is working.

Comment: That's IIS, not IIS Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing with this bug in IIS 10 I managed to transform from HTTP Error 503 into HTTP Error 403.14. For this case solution was to add

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
</system.webServer>
```

into project `Web.config` file.

Original info here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/405395/unable-to-get-anything-except-403-from-a-net-4-5-website

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem to my last post - I took out the added system statement above (only made things worse) then I enabled Directory Browsing and got web exactly that, web browsing of the folder for this site.   I then attempted to open the web.config file from the browser and got:

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

In my html code I then took out the statement that asked for an image since it was a MIME issue.  Then got the webpage properly without the image of course.

That took me to the stackoverflow fix which had me enable ASP.NET 4.7.
SUCCESS!  FIXED

Answer (score 0):

We may get http error 403.14 - forbidden if ASP.NET is disabled in Application Development Features section of Internet Information Services in Turn Windows Features on or off in Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features

[Make sure that ASP.NET is enabled in Application Development Features section of Internet Information Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yemG1.png)